# How do I get an instance method bound to a variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

How can I get an instance method in a variable?  For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

I want to be able to manipulate the "bar" instance method (for example, to pass it around).  How can I do it?

I know that I can get the class constant with

```
foo_class = Kernel.const_get("Foo")
```

Is there anything similar I can do to get `Foo#bar`?

Comment: class method `self.bar`?

Comment: Are you wanting to dynamically change how the bar method works or do you simply want to call the bar method so that it outputs 'bar'?

Comment: @fl00r:  That doesn't work.  I don't have an instance of the class.  @Scott Gottreu:  I want to be able to call it.

Comment: Where do you want to pass instance method? Normally it is bound to the object context and can't be called without it. Within object you can always create wrapper `lambda{ bar }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you need an [UnboundMethod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/UnboundMethod.html):

```
class Foo
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def bar
    @value
  end
end   

unbound_bar = Foo.instance_method(:bar)
p unbound_bar.bind(Foo.new("hello")).call
#=> "hello"
```

Comment: Hell to the yeah

Answer (score 0):

`method(:bar)` in the method scope. You can call that one, it's still bound to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

See the Ruby documentation for [UnboundMethod](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/UnboundMethod.html).